# Dynamically creating App.config with connection string if App.config does not exists in Application-Data folder

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config, configuration-files

I need to do my code the following task. I wrote some code as below, but I am getting error while setting connection string. Looks like it does not have set property.

1. Check if App.config is exists in user’s “Application Data” folder.
2. If does NOT exists then create App.config  with ConnectionString
3. If does exists   then check if it was connection string or not, and if missing then add connection string.

   ```
   string SomeConnectionString ="My Connection String goes here"

   //Checking whether App.config file exits in "Application Data" folder or not
     String appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath
                      (Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

     if (!File.Exists(appDataPath + "App.config"))
       {
          appDataPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath , "App.config");
          Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
                                 (appDataPath );
          var setting = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings
                        ["MyConnectionString"]; 

          if (setting == null) 
          { 
              Configuration Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
                                     (ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
              config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings
               ["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = SomeConnectionString; 
                //I am getting error on line above. Looks like there is not set 
                //property on it

           Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified,true);
           ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
         }

       }
       else
       {
           //check whether it has Connection string or not
           //if not then add connection string 
       }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The `app.config` is only that named in your program. During build process the file is renamed to `[ApplicationName].exe.config`. So name the file like this. **But beware!** Normally the program directory is not allowed for write access (only to administrators). Settings-API is the better way!!!!

Comment: I like the idea of using Setting.settings resolve this issue
Thank you Fischermaen

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) API? This might be more appropriate for what you are doing.

Comment: I like the idea of using Setting.settings resolve this issue
Thank you Brian